# Java Compile error: Parameter x is exceeding the limit of 255 words

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a constructor (for an auto generated class) that has 255 paremeters. Using ant on linux with javac 1.6.0_02. The class compiles fine and everything is good.

However when I try to compile the same class from within eclipse on windows xp with jdk 1.6, I get the following error

```
Too many parameters, parameter BLAH is exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters
```

`BLAH` is the the 256th parameter.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Changing the auto generated class is not an option as I would need to change it every compile or change the generator. Both options are not acceptable because we can already get this class on linux.

PS: For those who are interested, the java class is generated from an IDL file using JacORB. Unfortunately the number of parameters in the class can not be reduced as it defines an interfaces between our software and other systems.

Comment: I'd love to see the code that creates an instance of that class.

Comment: My bet is on this being a wsdl2java generated class.

Comment: whoaa... why so many parameters?

Comment: The java class is generated from an IDL file using JACORB, so you are free to look at it http://www.jacorb.org/

Comment: As an aside: the CLI doesn't have this limitation. Makes you wonder who thought it would ever be needed. :)

Comment: @hhafez: Don't blame JacORB ... or the CORBA IDL -> Java mapping.  The problem is in the design of the particular IDL interface that you are trying to use.

Comment: @Stephen C: Actually, no. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with having a class with more than 255 parameters. You might not understand why it is the case that doesn't make it a flawed design. I also did not blame JacORB plz re read my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well you're breaking the [VM specification, section 4.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659):

> The number of method parameters is
>   limited to 255 by the definition of a
>   method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the
>   limit includes one unit for this in
>   the case of instance or interface
>   method invocations. Note that a method
>   descriptor is defined in terms of a
>   notion of method parameter length in
>   which a parameter of type long or
>   double contributes two units to the
>   length, so parameters of these types
>   further reduce the limit.

I suggest you overcome the obstacles in changing the generated code... I'm pretty surprised it works on Linux, to be honest. I wouldn't be *entirely* surprised if the bytecode it generated was strictly invalid, and it just happens to be working for you at the moment.

While it's always tempting to try to find ways of keeping with the existing code and ignoring the limits, I think in this case you should turn your attention to reducing the number of parameters immediately.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: No, it looks like there are at least 256 parameters - hence "`BLAH` is the the 256th parameter" and "parameter BLAH is exceeding the limit of 255 words". Given that, I'm still surprised it works anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options to resolve this problem:

1. Generate your class with no or some constructor arguments and then set rest parameters via setters. Like using builder pattern.
2. Make simpler classes each holding 3 or 4 variables and set those simpler objects in 1 master class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [class file spec.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html) says:

> A method descriptor is valid only if it represents method parameters
>   with a total length of 255 or less, where that length includes the
>   contribution for this in the case of instance or interface method
>   invocations. The total length is calculated by summing the
>   contributions of the individual parameters, where a parameter of type
>   long or double contributes two units to the length and a parameter of
>   any other type contributes one unit.